# Suddenly seeing many instances of "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component"

Tags: reactjs

I'm suddenly getting the error in multiple components and I'm unable to get rid of it (and yes I know how to avoid updating a component's state when it's unmounted). I'm not sure what could be the cause of this sudden change so I'm not sure what info I can provide for additional context.

Comment: Can you show us some code where you're seeing this error?